# Flutter - Highlighting selected item in a ListView keeps showing when scrolling out of view

Tags: flutter, listview, highlight

I followed this solution to show what item is selected in a listview

[Flutter - select only single item in list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64610453/flutter-select-only-single-item-in-list-view)

I have some text items before the list view. The issue I have is when there are many items in the view so that I have to scroll to see the other items the highlight bar keeps on showing, the text will disappear but the bar will keep scrolling. Is this a bug or is there a way to stop the highlight bar from showing?

The red arrow shows the end of the list view widget.

[image]

As I scroll up the text will vanish but the bar stays

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug it seems. You have to wrap the listView in a Material Widget for now.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/86584